Proposition 5.13 of Atiyah and Macdonald
Proposition 5.12. Let $A \subset B$ be rings, $C$ the integral closure of $A$ in $B$. Let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$. Then $S^{-1}C$ is the integral closure of $S^{-1}A$ in $S^{-1}B$.
Definition: An integral domain is said to be integrally closed if it is integrally closed in its field of fractions.


Let $A$ be an integral domain. Then the following are
equivalent:
(i) $A$ is integrally closed;
(ii) $A_{\mathfrak p}$ is integrally closed, for each prime ideal $\mathfrak p$;
(iii) $A_{\mathfrak m}$ is integrally closed, for each maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.
Proof. Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$, let $C$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $K$,
and let $f: A \to C$ be the identity mapping of $A$ into $C$. Then $A$ is integrally
closed iff $f$ is surjective, and by (5.12) $A_{\mathfrak p}$ (resp. $A_{\mathfrak m}$) is integrally closed iff $f_{\mathfrak p}$ (resp.$f_{\mathfrak m}$) is surjective. Now use (3.9).

I can’t fill following detail in above proof: field of fraction of $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is $K_\mathfrak{p}$. We know $K_\mathfrak{p} = S^{-1}K=S^{-1}(\bar{S}^{-1} A)$ where $S=A-\mathfrak{p}$ and $\bar{S}=A-\{0\}$.

You just need to show that $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$, the field of fractions of $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, is the same as $(K)_{\mathfrak{p}}$, the localization of $K$ away from $\mathfrak{p}$. This is a "fractions of fractions" construction. See here.

@ArturoMagidin Thank you for the link.

(3.9) is a theorem that a module morphism $f\colon M\to N$ is injective (resp.~surjective) if and only if every localization at a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$,  $f_{\mathfrak{p}}\colon M_{\mathfrak{p}}\to N_{\mathfrak{p}}$, is injective (resp.~surjective), if and only if every localization at a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, $f_{\mathfrak{m}}\colon M_{\mathfrak{m}}\to N_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is injective (resp.~surjective).
So all you need to do is show that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, and $K$ is the field of fractions of $A$, then $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is $Q(A_\mathfrak{p})$, the field of fractions of $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Indeed, since $K$ is already a field, (the image of) every element of $A-\mathfrak{p}$ is already a unit in $K$, so $(A-\mathfrak{p})^{-1})K=K$. That is, $K_{\mathfrak{p}}=K$.
Now, since every element of $A-\mathfrak{p}$ maps to a unit under the canonical embedding $A\hookrightarrow K$, the universal property of localizations tells you that the map $A\hookrightarrow K$ induces a map $A_{\mathfrak{p}}\hookrightarrow K$. And because $K$ is a field, the universal property of the field of fractions tells that this map extends to a morphism $Q(A_{\mathfrak{p}})\to K$, which  must be injective since they are both fields. Conversely, the composition $A\to A_{\mathfrak{p}}\to Q(A_{\mathfrak{p}})$ maps $A$ into a field, and hence induces a morphism $K\to Q(A_{\mathfrak{p}})$. It is now easy to verify that these two maps are inverses of each other, so that we have $K_{\mathfrak{p}}=K=Q(A_{\mathfrak{p}})$. Now (3.9) gives the desired equivalence.

Thank you so much for the answer. For reference: explicit statement of “universal property of field of fraction” is corollary III.4.6 in Hungerford’s algebra. Composition $A\to A_\mathfrak{p}\to Q(A_\mathfrak{p})$ is injective and similarly it extended to $K\to Q(A_\mathfrak{p})$.
